# Space group of the honeycomb lattice

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, crystals

The question is simple: what is the space group of the 2-dimensional honeycomb (graphene) lattice?

I tried googling it. [One source (PDF)](https://www.ias.ac.in/public/Volumes/reso/024/04/0445-0457.pdf) says it is $P6/mmm$ (No. 191) (on the 11th page); [another](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-Honeycomb-crystal-structure-space-group-P-6-mcc-of-beryl-in-the-plane_fig1_269418421) says it is $P6/mcc$ (No. 192). I am super confused.

Comment: Is this a single layer? Or is this many layers? If it is a few layers, any compatible one will do.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Single layer, i.e. in 2 dimensions.

Comment: *I also asked GPT4* [Please don’t use computer-generated text for questions or answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14281/please-dont-use-computer-generated-text-for-questions-or-answers-on-physics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single layer graphene, if we are discussing the the simplistic ideal honeycomb graphene, would have point group D6H and therefore space group P6/mmm.

This makes sense to me as if we are talking about the perfect hexagonal sheet then its just a bunch of hexagons in all directions with D6H symmetry. Think the symmetry of benzene.

The only source I could find that discusses it in detail is here, page 18.

Fajardo, E. A., & Winkler, R. G. (2019). Effective dynamics of two-dimensional Bloch electrons in external fields derived from symmetry. Physical Review, 100(12). https://doi.org/10.1103/physrevb.100.125301

[image: symmetry of single layer graphene]

However, as you pointed out, not all what is referred to as "graphene" is in this form, and other forms exist, which can have different symmetries. Maybe this is why you found P6/mcc in some sources.